# Href gets changed when pasting html block into Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

When pasting a block of html into Lotus/IBM notes some of the links change (making them unusuable). Is it possible to switch this off?

Example:

When I try to paste this into notes

```
<a href="file:///\\myserver.com\link\to\file.type">click me<a/>
```

there seems to be some processing and it becomes:

```
<a href="file://myserver.com\link\to\file.type">click me<a/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put a " \" after the link. This seems to be able to enable the url slip under the notes reformatting radar without affecting the functionality. So the above example becomes:

```
<a href="file:///\\myserver.com\link\to\file.type \">click me<a/>
```